# Uninstall ZFS installed via Ubuntu 20.04 installer

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

Apologies if this has been answered somewhere, I've searched everywhere and couldn't find anything.

I'm a PhD student and I manage a small cluster for our group. When installing Ubuntu 20.04 on our servers we chose the "experimental" zfs feature. We've run into a few issues over the last two years and we never used ZFS to our advantage. We upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 we'd like to uninstall it now - but can we?

When I run `zpool list` I see `bpool` and `rpool` - so if I uninstalled the packages (not suer which ones since I didn't explicitly install them), would the system even boot? Clearly I don't know much about ZFS and shouldn't have installed it..

Obviously I would really like to avoid re-installing everything because it takes a really long time and things generally break. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's the requested output (although it sounds like I'm SOL).

```
$ sudo df -h
Filesystem                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                             6.3G  2.9M  6.3G   1% /run
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1                          830G   25G  805G   3% /
tmpfs                                              32G   16K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                             5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/www                  805G  128K  805G   1% /var/www
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/snap                 805G  3.9M  805G   1% /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/games                805G  128K  805G   1% /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/srv                      805G  128K  805G   1% /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/usr/local                841G   36G  805G   5% /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/spool                805G  256K  805G   1% /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib                  809G  4.1G  805G   1% /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/mail                 805G  128K  805G   1% /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/log                  805G  154M  805G   1% /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib/NetworkManager   805G  256K  805G   1% /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib/AccountsService  805G  128K  805G   1% /var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib/apt              806G  522M  805G   1% /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib/dpkg             805G   76M  805G   1% /var/lib/dpkg
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1                          1.8G  253M  1.6G  15% /boot
/dev/sda1                                         511M  7.1M  504M   2% /boot/efi
169.237.79.48:/mnt/home                           8.0T  1.7T  6.3T  22% /home
169.237.79.48:/mnt/data                            11T  7.8T  3.0T  73% /data
169.237.79.48:/mnt/backup                          12T   28G   12T   1% /backup
169.237.79.48:/mnt/nvme                           5.1T  3.8T  1.4T  74% /nvme

$ sudo df -hT
Filesystem                                       Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                            tmpfs  6.3G  2.9M  6.3G   1% /run
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1                         zfs    830G   25G  805G   3% /
tmpfs                                            tmpfs   32G   16K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                            tmpfs  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/www                 zfs    805G  128K  805G   1% /var/www
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/snap                zfs    805G  3.9M  805G   1% /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/games               zfs    805G  128K  805G   1% /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/srv                     zfs    805G  128K  805G   1% /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/usr/local               zfs    841G   36G  805G   5% /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/spool               zfs    805G  256K  805G   1% /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib                 zfs    809G  4.1G  805G   1% /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/mail                zfs    805G  128K  805G   1% /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/log                 zfs    805G  154M  805G   1% /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib/NetworkManager  zfs    805G  256K  805G   1% /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib/AccountsService zfs    805G  128K  805G   1% /var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib/apt             zfs    806G  522M  805G   1% /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1/var/lib/dpkg            zfs    805G   76M  805G   1% /var/lib/dpkg
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_3tmtm1                         zfs    1.8G  253M  1.6G  15% /boot
/dev/sda1                                        vfat   511M  7.1M  504M   2% /boot/efi
169.237.79.48:/mnt/home                          nfs    8.0T  1.7T  6.3T  22% /home
169.237.79.48:/mnt/data                          nfs     11T  7.8T  3.0T  73% /data
169.237.79.48:/mnt/backup                        nfs     12T   28G   12T   1% /backup
169.237.79.48:/mnt/nvme                          nfs    5.1T  3.8T  1.4T  74% /nvme

$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2714
loop2    7:2    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2721
loop3    7:3    0    73M  1 loop /snap/core22/607
loop4    7:4    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1828
loop5    7:5    0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137
loop6    7:6    0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop7    7:7    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1852
loop8    7:8    0 460.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/68
loop9    7:9    0  53.2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18933
loop10   7:10   0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop11   7:11   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/638
loop12   7:12   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/599
loop13   7:13   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop14   7:14   0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18596
loop16   7:16   0   428K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/57
loop17   7:17   0 241.9M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2559
loop18   7:18   0 460.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/87
loop19   7:19   0 241.9M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2579
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/grub
│                                /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0     2G  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0   927G  0 part
 
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: bpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:00:03 with 0 errors on Sun Apr  9 00:24:04 2023
config:

        NAME           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        bpool          ONLINE       0     0     0
          214bb022-06  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported and requested features are not enabled on the pool.
        The pool can still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
        the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
        the features. See zpool-features(7) for details.
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:29:07 with 0 errors on Sun Apr  9 00:53:13 2023
config:

        NAME           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool          ONLINE       0     0     0
          214bb022-07  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: Hello. Your a PhD student? don't worry, noobody is perfect :p. (sorry private joke).
Before uninstalling zfs (and pools) and breaking your data, may you provide the following output? (it will help to understand your config):
df -h, 
df -hT, 
lsblk,
zpool status,

thanks.

Comment: If ZFS was chosen during install, your rootfs is likely ZFS formatted so removing associated packages would be a bad idea and the only way to "fix" it would be to reinstall. The commands indicated by petitradisgris should help confirm whether or not that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "experimental" tag is for Ubuntu ZFS-on-root setup, not for ZFS-based data disks. In other words, you installed the OS itself (ie: Ubuntu) on ZFS. As such, you can't really uninstall ZFS - otherwise, the OS will not boot. You have to reinstall your system to get rid of ZFS.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I kind of thought..